# Capture from camera Image is not clear(Blurry) in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, mediastore

I Have a Problem with the Camera Capture Image.its set blurry.
I searched lots of but i can't Get Solutions
I don't know How to solve issue

Here is My Code Which i Used For Camera Capture Image
private void cameraIntent()
    {

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ///method to get Images
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        } else {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Your Permission is needed to get access the camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }


}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    byte[] imageInByte = bytes.toByteArray();
    long lengthbmp = imageInByte.length;

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    iv_upld.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

Comment: You need to activate the Autofocus

Comment: How to set  Autofocus when using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: it depends on your device camera not on code

Comment: @Omer i am testing approx 10 to 12 different phone but still found same issue.